# ipf is not present in AIX 7.1

Tags: aix

I am using AIX 7.1

bash-4.4# uname -a
AIX aix71 1 7 00FA2BC04C00

The documents from IBM is suggesting to use ipf for packet filtering

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.security/ipsec_filters_aix.htm

as per IBM suggestion as like below-

After installing the package, run the following command to load the kernel extension:
/usr/lib/methods/cfg_ipf -l

so I am facing below two issues--
1.How to install package for ipf
2./usr/lib/methods/cfg_ipf is by default is not present in AIX 7.1. How to get this cfg_ipf to load the kernel extension

Comment: Contact your IBM-Vendor.

Comment: Thanks for your response! But If I now going to load I am facing below problem--
bash-4.4#/usr/lib/methods/cfg_ipf -l
Major 525
devno 0
loadext: Permission denied
exec(): 0509-036 Cannot load program ipf because of the following errors:
Any clue about this ??

Comment: Please edit your original post and quote the error message (every line of it).